# Seaborn pairplot not showing KDE

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

After upgrading to matplotlib 2.0 I have a hard time getting seaborn to plot a pairplot.  For example...

`sns.pairplot(df.dropna(), diag_kind='kde')` returns the following error `TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method`.  My data doesn't have any Nans in it.  Infact, removing the kde option allows the function to run.

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Could you provide a [MCVE] as a test case that everyone can run and reproduce the error? This would help to identify if it is a problem depending on the data in use or a general problem between matplotlib, seaborn and pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Check the data type of the relevant variables.  The error indicates that at least one of them is not an integer.  It might be a float. If so, you'll need to recast the variable as an integer.  Be careful if you have some very long numbers as these can round down when converting to an integer - see [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569528/python-float-to-int-conversion) for more information.

(Note, this works for me in Python 2.7, not sure if 3.+ is different).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was with statsmodels (which seaborn uses to do KDE).  I reinstalled statsmodels and that cleared up the problem.