# Python 3 Removing All Decimal numbers from float but keep decimal

Tags: python, stripping

I wanted to create numbered bullet points.

Decided the way I wanted to do it was

Strip a float of all numbers behind the decimal, but keep the decimal.

Example: 
2.0 would be 2.
3.14 would be 3.

Is there way to do it this way?
If so what would it look like?

Once again, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, there are several ways to do so

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python float to int conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569528/python-float-to-int-conversion)

Comment: If you want to stay the `dot` after the number its not possible using `integer`s or `float`s but maybe using `string`s.

Comment: Just for fun: float(str(5.57).split('.')[0] + '.0')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str(int(x)) + "."
```

Converting back to float would add a zero after the decimal, so it has to be left in string.

Comment: Thanks every. Ok Azhy said not possible the way I wanted to do it, and this was quick and easy fix to get the effect I wanted. Again thank everyone for taking the time to read and those who responded

Answer (score 1):

One way to do so would be to first use int to just obtain the integer part of the float. Then if you just want a number like `3.` this is impossible without converting to string since `3.` give `3.0`. So perhaps convert the integer part to a string then concatenate a period of the form `'3.'`
An example:

```
In [1]: num = 3.14

In [2]: myint = int(num)

In [3]: myint
Out[3]: 3

In [4]: mystr = str(myint)

In [5]: mystr
Out[5]: '3'

In [6]: mystr += '.'

In [7]: mystr
Out[7]: '3.'
```

or in one step:

```
mystr = str(int(num)) + '.'
```

giving the output of `'3.'` given the input `num = 3.14`:

```
In [12]: mystr
Out[12]: '3.'
```