# Python integer and float multiplication error

Tags: python, numpy, integer, multiplication

The question seems dummy, but I cannot get it right. The output `cm1` is expected to be floats, but I  only get zeros and ones.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial.distance
sim  = scipy.spatial.distance.cosine
a = [2, 3, 1]
b = [3, 1, 2]
c = [1, 2, 6]
cm0 = np.array([a,b,c])
ca, cb, cc = 0.9, 0.7, 0.4 
cr = np.array([ca, cb, cc])
cm1 = np.empty_like(cm0)
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        cm1[i,j] = cm0[i,j] * cr[i] * cr[j]
print(cm1)
```

And I get:

```
[[1 1 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]
```

Comment: `empy_like` matches the `cm0` dtype (`int`).  Don't use it if you want floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`empty_like()` [matches the type](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-empty_like-python/) of the given numpy array by default, as [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) suggested in the comments. In your case `cm0` is of type integer.

The `empty_like` function accepts multiple arguments though, one of wich is `dtype`. Setting `dtype` to `float` should solve the problem:

```
cm1 = np.empty_like(cm0, dtype=float)
```

And also Python truncates floating point numbers at the decimal point when [converting to integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569528/python-float-to-int-conversion). In your case, every multiplication done results in a number between `1.89` and `0.36`, so flooring the results will result in `0`s and `1`s respectively.

Comment: Thanks all for your fast response, appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As @hpaulj said in the comments section, the problem is using `empty_like` which will keep the `cm0` `dtype`, to solve it try:

```
cm1 = np.empty_like(cm0, dtype=float)
```