# Conversion of a large float to an int

Tags: python

Suppose I have this large number,x

3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333 (which I want)

and this large number,n
3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333.0.

When I convert n into an int through the round function, it provides me with a completely different number, which I suppose is because of floating point precision limitations.

Is there anyway to round of that number into a integer. I don't have to worry about any other decimal points, just .0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python float to int conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569528/python-float-to-int-conversion)

Comment: You *don't have* 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333.0. You have 3333333333333333640373015225566689909307473186543079037861888.0.

Comment: @MarkHill, I was looking at changing a large number (more than 16 digits) thats in floating point without any following decimal except for the .0, into an integer whilst not sacrificing the length of the number.

Comment: Floats have limited storage space available. Just pasting that number into the interpreter you'll get `3.3333333333333336e+60`. That float never had that value to begin with, and of course converting it to an int won't make it any better.

Comment: If you store `n` as a float, you have already lost precision. So there's no way it can be reliably converted to your desired int. For example, `3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333.0 == 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333334.0` is `True` - two different integers correspond to the **same** float.

Comment: @mkrieger1, I kow that, I wanted to know how I could work around that number to produce 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333 this instead of 3333333333333333640373015225566689909307473186543079037861888.0.

Comment: The only way around that is to not use floats.

Comment: You should think of int -> float (for large numbers) like a lossy compression. If you convert a WAV to an MP3, you can't convert the MP3 perfectly back to the original WAV.

Comment: Please show an actual [mre] code so that we know what you are dealing with exactly.

Comment: Try to construct a real example.  What is the type of your starting value?  Is it `float`?  If so, then it cannot be `3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333.0`.  You you want a more precise fixed point value, consider using `decimal.Decimal`, which *can* represent that number.  Or consider using `fractions.Fraction`.  Again, you need to specify the type of the starting value.

Comment: Tom's comment is the only real answer to this, though if your starting value _is_ a float, then how do you expect to reconstruct the data? What if it isn't just a lot of the same number? Technically this works for the _specific_ example you have, impossible to accurately reconstruct any other number though: `int(str(num)[0] * int(str(num).split('+')[1]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from decimal import Decimal

print(int(Decimal("3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333.0")))
```

Output:

```
3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
```