# Rounding Problem with Python

Tags: python, rounding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python rounding error with float numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997027/python-rounding-error-with-float-numbers)

I have a rounding Problem in Python. If i calculate

32.50 * 0.19 = 6.1749999999999998

But this should be 6.175. If i round 6.1749999999999998 with 2 decimal places it correctly shows 6.18. So i can live with that.

But if i calculate this:

32.50 * 0.19 * 3 = 18.524999999999999

This should be 18.525. If i round the value 18.524999999999999 with two decimal places it shows 18.52.

It should show me 18.53. What am i doing wrong and how can i fix it ?

Comment: Try `print 32.50 * 0.19` or `print 32.50 * 0.19 * 3`. Python knows how to correctly display those floating point values. As long as that is the case, you're as close as a computer will be to the correct (decimal) value with floating point storage. If you really need an _exact_ answer (you don't) use `Decimal.decimal`.

Comment: -1.  Typing the title of this post into StackOverflow's search easily finds answers to this question.  -1 is for not putting forth the effort to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need exact arithmetic, you could use the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/modindex.html#cap-D) module:

```
import decimal
D=decimal.Decimal

x=D('32.50')*D('0.19')
print(x)
# 6.1750
print(x.quantize(D('0.01'),rounding=decimal.ROUND_UP))
# 6.18

y=D('32.50')*D('0.19')*D('3')
print(y)
# 18.5250
print(y.quantize(D('0.01'),rounding=decimal.ROUND_UP))
# 18.53
```

Comment: He doesn't really need `Decimal` though, he just doesn't understand how floating point works.

Comment: @agf: How do you know what he needs? It's entirely possible he's dealing with money, which shouldn't be done with floating point.

Comment: exact iam dealing with money so i will try this thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

In short - you should not rely on precise values of float numbers because of the way they are stored in the memory.

See also python docs about it - [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues). It contains the next passage:

> For example, if you try to round the value 2.675 to two decimal places, you get this
>
> `>>> round(2.675, 2)`
>   `2.67`
>
> The documentation for the built-in round() function says that it
>   rounds to the nearest value, rounding ties away from zero. Since the
>   decimal fraction 2.675 is exactly halfway between 2.67 and 2.68, you
>   might expect the result here to be (a binary approximation to) 2.68.
>   It’s not, because when the decimal string 2.675 is converted to a
>   binary floating-point number, it’s again replaced with a binary
>   approximation, whose exact value is
>
> 2.67499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875
>
> Since this approximation is slightly closer to 2.67 than to 2.68, it’s
>   rounded down.

Comment: Although the docs nor the tutorial didn't get updated, in Python 2.7.4 `round(2.675, 2)` will now give `2.68` as expected.

Comment: @Neftas: What do you base that claim on?  On my machine with Python 2.7.6, `round(2.675, 2)` rounds down, just as described in the documentation.  There haven't been any significant changes to the `round` algorithm since Python 2.7.0.

Comment: You're right, @MarkDickinson. At the time I wrote that, I tried it out of course, but now my new installation of Python 2.7.3 rounds down. So it was probably a mistake on my side.

Comment: @Neftas: Okay, that makes sense.  The history of the `round` function is quite a mess: it *mostly* rounds halfway cases up in Python 2.6, *always* rounds halfway cases up in Python 2.7, and *always* rounds halfway cases to the nearest even result in Python >= 3.1. Except that of course thanks to the underlying binary representation, things that *look* like halfway cases in decimal aren't necessarily actual halfway cases.

Comment: Not something you would want to rely on then in your code, obviously. It's probably best to always use the `decimal` module for this kind of division (as recommended in the Python reference).

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) Module from python to do accurate floating arithmatic

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_UP

value = Decimal(32.50 * 0.19 * 3)
print (value.quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_UP))
```

---

```
Output: 18.53
```

Comment: He doesn't really need `Decimal` though, he just doesn't understand how floating point works.

Comment: The OP asked how to fix it (`Decimal`). The Link also explains why the OP is having this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing nothing wrong, and [it isn't Python's fault either](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). Some decimal numbers just cannot be precisely represented as binary floats.

Just like you can't write `1/3` in decimal (`0.33333....`), you can't write decimal `0.1` in binary (`0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011...`).

**Solution A:**

Use `print 32.5 * 0.19` - it will automatically round the result.

**Solution B:**

Use the [`Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module if you actually need this precision, for example when calculating with monetary values.

**Solution C:**

Use Python 3.2 or Python 2.7 which will automatically round the result in an interactive session.

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 14:24:46) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 32.50 * 0.19
6.175
```

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#round

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is wrong.  Take this from the Python interpreter:

```
>>> round(18.524999999999999,2)
18.52
>>> round(6.1749999999999998,2)
6.17
>>>
```

In both cases, the number being rounded was less than 5, so it rounded down.  18.52, and 6.17.

That is correct.

One thing I don't get is why you are getting 6.18, and I get 6.17.  I am using Python 3.2.2 (the latest version)

Comment: Because he doesn't have exactly that number, that is just the `repr` of the number he's really got.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong. This is due to the internal representation of the numbers:

For example, try this:

```
0.1 + 0.1 +  0.1 + 0.1 +  0.1 + 0.1 +  0.1 + 0.1 +  0.1 + 0.1
```

If you need more precision use the decimal representation