# in Python how to convert number to float in a mixed list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings in the form like

```
a = ['str','5','','4.1']
```

I want to convert all numbers in the list to float, but leave the rest unchanged, like this

```
a = ['str',5,'',4.1]
```

I tried

```
map(float,a)
```

but apparently it gave me an error because some string cannot be converted to float. I also tried

```
a[:] = [float(x) for x in a if x.isdigit()]
```

but it only gives me

```
[5]
```

so the float number and all other strings are lost. What should I do to keep the string and number at the same time?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear, the list can be long and I do not know the exact order of the elements, meaning I do not know which one is number before hand.

Comment: Did you try doing `'4.1'.isdigit()`, or reading [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)? "Return true if all characters in the string are digits…" Since `'.'` is not a digit, it returns false.

Comment: @abarnert, you are right. I was wrong about 4.1 and it's now fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    try:
        a[i] = float(x)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

This assumes you want to change `a` in place, for creating a new list you can use the following:

```
new_a = []
for x in a:
    try:
        new_a.append(float(x))
    except ValueError:
        new_a.append(x)
```

This try/except approach is standard [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) and will be more efficient and less error prone than checking to see if each string is a valid float.

Comment: The one-liner example will fail on `4.1` since the dot character is not a digit.  Replacing `if i.isdigit()` with `if i.replace('.','').isdigit()` should get around that problem.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that, I just removed the one liner since you would also run into issues with negative numbers and scientific notation.  Easier to just do the try/except.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> a = ['str','5','','4.1']
>>> a2 = []
>>> for s in a:
...     try:
...         a2.append(float(s))
...     except ValueError:
...         a2.append(s)
>>> a2
['str', 5.0, '', 4.0999999999999996]
```

If you're doing decimal math, you may want to look at the decimal module:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> for s in a:
...     try:
...         a2.append(decimal.Decimal(s))
...     except decimal.InvalidOperation:
...         a2.append(s)
>>> a2
['str', Decimal('5'), '', Decimal('4.1')]
```

Comment: Thanks. But why do I get 4.0999999999999996? I would like to have same significant figure as the original number.

Comment: @LWZ - thats the way floating point numbers work. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997027/python-rounding-error-with-float-numbers).

Comment: @LWZ: Because you cannot represent `4.1` exactly as a `float`. There are roughly 69105.00000000000001 questions on SO about this, so search if you need more info.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to do it without *exception handling* and using a bit of *regex*: -

```
>>> a = ['str','5','','4.1']
>>> import re
>>> [float(x) if re.match("[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)$", x) else x for x in a]
4: ['str', 5.0, '', 4.1]
```

Note that, this regex will cover only a basic range of numbers, applicable in your case. For more elaborate regex to match a wider range of floating-point numbers, like, including exponents, you can take a look at this question: -

- [Extract float/double value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385558/python-and-regex-question-extract-float-double-value)

Comment: Is it worth anchoring with ``$`` in the ``re``  ``"\d+(\.\d+)?$"``for the pathological cases of '3.14pi' etc. Best answer none the less.

Comment: Your solution misses negative numbers, isn't it? All in all, it is almost never a good idea to use regexps unless they're really required.

Comment: @Vladimir.. Yeah, updated it. Didn't consider all cases on first go, based on the input by OP.

Comment: Also, `.5` and `1.` are still valid float point literals in python ;)

Comment: It seems, the right regexes have been presented at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385558/python-and-regex-question-extract-float-double-value .

Comment: Also misses floats expressed in scientific notation like `3.1e2`

Comment: @bgporter.. Yeah right. And that is why I've quoted this thing in my answer, with a link to another answer containing the actual regex.

Answer (score 4):

My version:

```
def convert(value):
    try:
        return float(value)
    except ValueError:
        return value

map(convert, a)
```