# Why Python string to float will not be exact the same value?

Tags: python

Assuming I have three line of python code

```
text = "0.965"
value = float(text)
print value
```

My question is, when they display the output, why my python show `0.9649999999999999` instead if `0.965`. I know I can use round to get rid of this problem, but I just wondering why this is the case? I though I should just get the `0.965`?

Thanks for you answering.

Comment: Erm, I meant to use [Python rounding error with float numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5997027) instead. But both are fine. :-)

Comment: see here [http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) for an explanation as well as how to use `Decimal` to enforce the desired accuracy