# different result in python on multiplying same numbers as integer vs floating

Tags: python, multiplication

tried multiplication of 109221975*123222821 in python 2.7 prompt in two different ways

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:08:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 109221975*123222821
13458639874691475L
>>> 109221975*123222821.0
1.3458639874691476e+16
>>> int(109221975.0*123222821.0)
13458639874691476L
>>> 109221975*123222821 == int(109221975.0*123222821.0)
False
>>>
```

what I am suspecting here is that there is some precision inconsistency which is causing such problem , is it possible to speculate when can inconsistency like this happen ?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Sigh. Another day, another FP confusion. Please read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: There should be a warning before you post if float is anywhere in your question text to read that article first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python rounding error with float numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997027/python-rounding-error-with-float-numbers)

Comment: @IanAuld: To be fair, if you actually tag the question [floating-point] you sort of do get that warning. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once upon a time, there was a string named `st` that wanted to be a number. What number should I be said st?

The string's fairy god mother said: Well st, if you want to be an accurate number, a number for counting whole things, I would be an arbitrary precision integer:

```
>>> st='123456789123456789'
>>> int(st)
123456789123456789
>>> int(st)*int(st)*int(st)
1881676377434183981909562699940347954480361860897069
```

'But I also want to count partial things, like the 1/2 of the sandwich I still have!' said st. So be a float said the fair godmother, but know that you may loose track of a few 1/2 sandwiches after a while. In fact, after `9007199254740992` things you may start to forget a few because you only have 53 fingers to count with when you are a float:

```
>>> float(int('1'*53,2)+1)
9007199254740992.0
>>> float(int('1'*53,2)+1)+1
9007199254740992.0

>>> int(float(int(st)))
123456789123456784
>>> int(st)-int(float(st))
5
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `int` is 54 bits long. `float` can hold 53 significant digits, so effectively the last digit is rounded to an even number.

Internally, your float is represented as:

> 2225720309975242*2<sup>-1</sup>

Your `int` and `float` is stored in binary like the following:

```
             101111110100001000111111001000111001000001000110010011
0 10000110100 0111111010000100011111100100011100100000100011001010
```

For `float`, the first part is the **sign**, the second is the **exponent**, and the third is the **significand**. Because space is allocated for an exponent, there isn't enough room left over for  the significant digits

How I aligned the two representations, you can see the data is the same, but the `int` needs one extra digit on the right, while the `float` uses more (in this case wasted) space on the left

Comment: For those curious, I extracted the binary of the float using `struct.unpack('Q', struct.pack('d', number))`

Answer (score 1):

Because `int` in python has infinite precision, but `float` does not. (`float` is a double precision floating point number, which has 53 bits of precision.)