# Checking if the a number is a whole cube

Tags: python, math

I'm a beginner in python and have written a code to check if a number is a cube of a whole number. The code seems to be working fine for some values, however for some (even whole cubes) it prints the cube root as (`x-0.000000004`, `x` being cube root). Example it will give `3.9999999996` as the cube root of 64 but will print 2,5 for 8,125 . Any thoughts?

```
n=int(input("Please enter the number: "))
print (n)
x=n**(1/3)
print (x)
if x==int(x):
    print ('%s is a whole cube'%(n))
else:
    print ('%s is not a whole cube'%(n))
```

Ignore the intermediate print statements, they're just for line-by-line debugging.

Comment: Highly recommended read [Python rounding error with float numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997027/python-rounding-error-with-float-numbers)

Comment: This is one of the most asked questions. Please read some topics about floating point precision. For example the one Bhargav Rao mentioned.

Comment: Sorry for the repetition guys. will check out the python docs, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are checking for the wrong condition, comparing floats value for equality can easily give you nightmares. Check what the [python docs have to say on this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Instead, round the  root, convert it to an int, and then compare the cube of this integer with the original number:

```
n = int(input("Please enter the number: "))
print (n)
x = n**(1/3)
x = int(round(x))
if x**3 == n:
    print ('%s is a whole cube'%(n))
else:
    print ('%s is not a whole cube'%(n))
```

As pointed by @StevenRumbalski in comments, in Python3, `x = int(round(x))` could be written as `round(x)` since `round` returns `int`.

Comment: In Python 3 `round` returns an integer when called with one argument, so if OP is using Python 3 he can skip the cast to `int`.

Comment: You can skip the `round()`, too. `int(3.7)` is `3`. So the condition `if int(n**(1.0/3))**3 == n` could be used. I think this works in both Python 2 and 3.