# Python3.4 subtraction incorrect result. Interpreter output the answer of 4 - 3.2 as 0.799999

Tags: python, python-3.x

While i'm playing around with the python interpreter, i noticed that it outputs the value 0.7999999999999998, as the answer of 4-3.2 (4 subtract by 3.2) which is not correct. What is the reason for this? Isn't this going to be effected to those who use python programs in their businesses?
How can i solve this in python?

Comment: there is no particular method specified to solve this problem in that Q

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5997103/2301450

Comment: Difficult to tell you the solution without knowing what the problem is. We don't know the full details of your requirements. You asked why Python produced the output that it does.