# Python rounding and inserting into array does not round

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, rounding

There is a post [about broken rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997027/python-rounding-error-with-float-numbers) . However it is not a rounding problem here because it does round in the normal case as you see but it doesn't round when inserting into an array.

I have following code:

```
print(round(limits[1],1))
limit = [round(limits[0],1), round(limits[1],1)]
print(limit)
```

Output:

```
25860.4
[14766.4, 25860.400000000001]
```

I do not understand why second element of an array is not rounded, although I do round it before while I pack it into the array.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
def intrvl_comparison(data):
    m = np.mean(data)
    sd = np.std(data)
    up_l = (m + sd)
    low_l = (m - sd)
    limits = [low_l, up_l]
    limit = [round(x,1) for x in limits]
    print(round(limits[0],1))
    limit = [round(limits[0],1), round(limits[1],1)]
    print(limit)

intrvl_comparison([2.66666,4.4444444,6066,9999])
```

Comment: What python version are you using? This seems to be an issue with pre-2.7 versions.

Comment: I have Python 3.6.0

Comment: I'll try to reproduce this on my machine. Could you please provide a minimal code I could run?

Comment: @gonczor I included a code into the question

Comment: Added 3.x tag, as I can reproduce this in Python 3 at repl.it, but not on my machine in 2.7

Comment: Thanks, I've tried playing around with it and if I call limit[0] == - 230.4 it returns True meaning it could have more to do with representation than with actual value. You could check out Decimal library, or use formatting for printouts if it doesn;t affect the logic of your code. Sorry, I don't know this issue.

Comment: For what it's worth, there are two effects here. First is the fact that `repr` is used when printing elements of a collection, as opposed to the `str` that's used when printing an element directly. That's covered in the linked so-called duplicate. But that's not enough to explain what's being seen here, since in Python >= 3.2, the `repr` and `str` of a Python `float` are identical. The other piece of information that you need is that you're looking at NumPy `float64` objects, which use a different `repr` algorithm from Python floats. ...

Comment: ... So you're seeing the difference between `str` and `repr` for NumPy `float64` objects. But the underlying message of the linked answers holds: the values aren't changing; it's merely that they're being displayed differently in the two cases.