# Let Python find two integers satisfying condition

Tags: python, integer, set, conditional-statements

**Set-up**

I'm looking for all the integer pairs `(x,y)` in 2 closed sets: `[822,2000]` and `[506,1231]` such that `x/y=1.624`.

---

**Code so far**

I tried,

```
a = [[(x,y)] for x in range(822,2001) and y in range(506,1232) if x/y = 1.624]
```

But this gives a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` pointing to the `=` in the code.

And if I do,

```
a = [[(x,y)] for x in range(822,2001) and y in range(506,1232) if x/y <= 1.624]
```

I get `NameError: name 'y' is not defined`.

How do I solve this?

Comment: `=` is assignment operator, for comparison use `==`

Comment: what @bro-grammer says for the first line, and for the second - you mean `for y in` not `and y in`... and you probably want `[(x, y)`... instead of `[[(x, y]`... unless you really want a list of one element lists instead of a list of tuples...

Comment: @bro-grammer (cc JonClements) Hm... it looks like that the higher-rep users get an unfair (?) advantages of being able to give hints in comment?

Comment: Thanks for helping this dummy out. Solved it.

Comment: @user202729 I believe hints should always be in comments.

Comment: ... Then users with < 50 rep can't give hints? Well... no wonder why they keep complaining.

Comment: @user202729 nobody hinders users with 1 rep to try to answer things - it is possible to gain 50 rep and then be able to comment - not easy, just possible :) and commments do not get you any rep as is, so experienced users giving hints might help less experienced ones to get to an answer and to rep.

Comment: @user202729 [have a look at this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: @PatrickArtner Good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing float calculations with == is difficult due to the nature of float arithmetics.

It is often better to compare like this:

```
a = [(x,y) for x in range(822,2001) for y in range(506,1232) if abs(x/y - 1.624) < 0.00001] 
print(set(a))
```

By substracting the wanted value from your result and and comparing its absolute value against something kindof small you get better results.

Result (using a set):

```
{(1624, 1000), (1637, 1008), (1015, 625), (1611, 992), (1840, 1133), 
 (1814, 1117), (1827, 1125), (1408, 867), (1218, 750), (1434, 883), 
 (1421, 875)}
```

[Python rounding error with float numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997027/python-rounding-error-with-float-numbers)

Comment: There is also [math.isclose](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-485-a-function-for-testing-approximate-equality), but only available for `python>=3.5`

Answer (score 2):

For the first one you are using the assignment operator instead of the equivalent operator so it should be:

`a = [[(x,y)] for x in range(822,2001) and y in range(506,1232) if x/y == 1.624]`

And for the second you're probably better off using two for loops

`a = [[(x,y)] for x in range(822,2001) for y in range(506,1232) if x/y <= 1.624]`

The second one would not make sense as you said it because x and y are coming from lists that have an unequal number of elements so you cannot loop over them like that