# Inconsistent Decimal arithmetic in Python (rounding errors)

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('0.3637') * (Decimal('1') / Decimal('0.9323')) == Decimal('0.3637') / Decimal('0.9323')
False
```

Why?

I thought decimal module solves problems with rounding in floating point arithmetic.
How to check the equality of two decimal numbers in Python?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, returns `True` for me (once I fix the errant `)`)

Comment: Because `(Decimal('1')/Decimal('0.9323')) = Decimal('1.072616110693982623619006757')` . And hence `Decimal('0.3637') * Decimal('1.072616110693982623619006757') != Decimal('0.3637')/Decimal('0.9323')`.

Answer (score 1):

**Observation**

Order of operations is critical to understand *why* you are seeing the result:

```
from decimal import Decimal as D

D('0.3637') * (D('1') / D('0.9323')) == D('0.3637') / D('0.9323')
# False

(D('0.3637') * D('1')) / D('0.9323') == D('0.3637') / D('0.9323')
# True
```

**Explanation**

The reason is [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5997103/9209546), excerpt below. Decimal arithmetic is still fundamentally finite precision.

You *can* and should, if it matters to you, reduce precision using `getcontext().prec`. See `decimal` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) for more details.

> In general decimal is probably going overboard and still will have
>   rounding errors in rare cases when the number does not have a finite
>   decimal representation (for example any fraction where the denominator
>   is not 1 or divisible by 2 or 5 - the factors of the decimal base
>   (10)).

**Solution**

For general comparison of floats:

**[What is the best way to compare floats for almost-equality in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)**