# assigning decimals to a variable Python

Tags: python

Good evening All,

I need help with python project. I am interested in knowing the following.

Let's say I am multiplying 2 numbers together in python.

number = x * y

lets say x is = 3 and y is = 3.2

the total is 9.6

Now I am interested in that .6

I want to assign that `.6` to a variable so I can multiply it later on..

how can I assign `.6` to a variable?

I tried using the following:

```
a = 123.4
number_dec = str(a-int(a))[1:]
a2 = number_dec * 2
```

but it does not work... please help

Comment: I suggest you check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997027/python-rounding-error-with-float-numbers)

Answer (score 4):

Python supports modulo operations on floating point numbers, so you can do this with

```
>>> 9.6 % 1
0.5999999999999996
```

Note that this won't give you what you want if the number is negative:

```
>>> -9.6 % 1
0.40000000000000036
```

So in general you'll want

```
frac = abs(value) % 1
```

This is the fastest of the ones I looked at:

```
%timeit frac = abs(value) % 1
77.1 ns ± 0.568 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

%timeit frac = abs(value) % int(value)
196 ns ± 5.77 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit frac = value - int(value)
156 ns ± 2.42 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Comment: `value % int(value)`

Comment: That is a bit repetitive, and takes a bit over twice as long.

Comment: But it works with negative numbers

Comment: Yes, but so does taking the absolute value first, which is really fast.

Comment: But `-0.6` is the correct answer.

Comment: Ah - that isn't clear from the OPs question. :)

Answer (score 2):

given an integer [int()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) truncates the fractional part, so with

```
n = 4.5
fractional = n - int(n) #0.5
```

you can get it.

Answer (score 1):

Even easier approach using strings would be :

```
number = 123.4    
number_dec = str(number).split(".")[1]
print(number_dec)
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comment: @PeterWood this won’t give a single character, it will give everything after the `.`, which is just what the OP asked for. (Well, until you try it on a float whose string representation requires exponential notation…)

Comment: >  Also I assume the example was just for a single decimal place but really they want something more general.
I think you missed something.

Comment: My mistake. Deleted.