# I understand Python (3.x) is supposed to round to even. Why is round(0.975,2) = 0.97 but round(0.975*100)/100 = 0.98?

Tags: python, rounding, precision

So the question is in the title. Here are some more details:

code:

```
a=0.975
print(round(a,2))
print(round(a*100)/100)

a=-0.975
print(round(a,2))
print(round(a*100)/100)

a=1.975
print(round(a,2))
print(round(a*100)/100)

a=-1.975
print(round(a,2))
print(round(a*100)/100)
```

The printed output is:

```
0.97
0.98
-0.97
-0.98
1.98
1.98
-1.98
-1.98
```

I guess there is something going on with floating point error and how `round()` handles float numbers?
It seems to be the case between -1 and 1. Probably `round()` is shifting the floating point and creating a number with more digits after the 5?

Can someone explain, whether there is a way to avoid this?

Comment: Duplicate of [Python rounding error with float numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997027/python-rounding-error-with-float-numbers). See also https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: The value of the first `a` is actually 0.97499999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375. The others have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known isue with floating points with Python.
You can see the real value Python is storing as decimal point with the decimal library:

```
from decimal import Decimal

print(Decimal(0.975)
```

To avoid this issue you can just use de decimal library before the round operation.

```
from decimal import Decimal

a = 0.975
print(float(round(Decimal(str(a)),2)))
```

This will print the desired 0.98 result.

Here you have the Decimal library documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html